# Does a Paladin's fire immunity decrease Fireball's damage?

Tags: spells, damage, paladin, dungeon-world, resistance

I have looked around and could not find a definitive answer either way.

Scenario:

Paladin is surrounded by a bunch of goblins hacking them. I cast a fireball at the Paladin who has 3 armor and an immunity to fire as a boon. I roll well enough to maximize the damage, eg 12.

How much damage does the Paladin take?

Comment: BTW - it's sometimes a good idea to hold off on accepting an answer for a few days. Some users are put off of answering a question that's already got an accepted answer and you can rob yourself and the community of some good input by being so quick on the click.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## None*.

<sub>*None is provided as-is and considering only the idea that "invulnerability to fire" means that fire can't touch your hit points. Actual effects of invulnerability to fire can range from "body is fine but not any carried or worn objects" to "a projected aura of divine force where fire holds no purchase". Consult with the Paladin and the forces granting the boons for the Paladin's Quest to determine how the boon operates. None does not cover things the GM may wish to *tell you the requirements or consequences* about, such as suddenly volatilized poisons, ignited shrapnel grenades, or standing on a rickety goblin platform that collapses in splinters and ash. Ask your GM if none is right for you.</sub>

### Or, the long way:

Invulnerability to something means you're **not vulnerable** to it. It can't hurt you. That's more of a fictional thing than a mechanical one, meaning there's space there for questions like "is the stuff in your backpack sufficiently a part of you to also be unaffected by fire?" or "is the Apocalypse Dragon breathing fire or just a gout of chaos that usually just works like fire but there's other bad stuff in there too?" But central to the fictional thing is the idea that **fire can't hurt you**, and if something can't hurt you, it would be really weird if it knocked down your hit points anyway.

So, friendly fire isn't an option here. But much as it's a fictional thing that the Paladin is invulnerable to fire, it's also a fictional thing that you just engulfed a large area in powerful flames. Of course that hurts things with fire, but it also does the things that engulfing an area in flames would do, such as collapsing structures or burning things into noxious fumes or touching off explosions. In this way, even though the Paladin can deal readily with the **phenomenon** of fire without putting their hit points or other things at risk, they may at the GM's option still have to struggle with the **consequences** of fire.

Answer (score 5):

## Some. Maybe?

This is the kind of thing that is really a question for your table, not us, nor the rulebook.

Is your fireball...*just **fire**?* You're The Wizard in this scenario, you tell us. If it's fire, then the Paladin is invulnerable - their person takes no damage (see great answer by @Glazius).

**But:** Then it's also *just fire*. Which means you cast it underwater and it's wasted. Someone on the other side of a waterfall may also be safe, or suffer reduced damage. Cast it in a sealed room and enjoy your last moments of consciousness as the fireball greedily consumes all the oxygen and you pass out and then die.

If, on the other hand, it's not *just fire*, if it's more esoteric - like the extension into this universe of the fingertip of the sun god - then it may **look** like a fireball but it's not *just fire*. In which case it comes with its own set of powers and limitations, including that the Paladin is just going to have to suck it up with the rest of the targets, but there's a good argument to be made that it works underwater and through waterfalls and won't eat all your oxygen, etc.

This is the kind of worldbuilding that Dungeon World encourages and embraces - this is why the answer you seek isn't in the book - because it exists only at the table and is true at the moment you make it true.

Comment: Agreed. Ask the wizard what a fireball is. Ask the Paladin if a ball of fire would hurt them if they are immune to fire.